# Azure B2C Custom Email OTP 'Create Account' Disable

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have been working through the custom OTP email guidance from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

However, after entering the validation code, I cannot actually Create account, as the button is disabled.

[image]

Can anybody suggest (in general) where my custom policy might be going wrong? I am hesitant to post all of my custom policy xml, as it is quite lengthy and includes other features that are a challenge to sanitize for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess from one screenshot, but I would check and update all content definitions (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions) and pagelayout versions (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout).

I've had to update both to make custom OTP emails work for our custom policy.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I posted the answer, it ended up being due to a coworker writing some sneaky javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a co-worker had some custom javascript running in the custom html for our custom policy. It was mucking about with button properties, improperly. So, the policy file seems to have been fine!